# Display ProgressDialog until AsyncTask finishes, then update UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

This is the flow of my app:

1) The user takes a picture or video

2) The media is saved to internal storage

3) The path is assigned to a custom object

4) The UI is updated to indicate that the user can continue

The UI updates only if the custom object has either an imagepath or a videopath. I've just started using `AsyncTask` to save to internal storage in a background thread so the app will not hang while saving large files, but I'm having some problems.

**What I want to do: Display a `ProgressDialog` until `doInBackground()` finishes, then assign the path to my Object, and *then* continue on the main thread to update the UI.**

Right now, the main thread will continue while `AsyncTask` is still working, and the UI will not update correctly since the path has not yet been assigned to the Object.

I've read about `AsyncTask#get()`, but I'm not sure how to implement it with the `ProgressDialog`. I tried, and the main thread didn't seem to wait for the results before continuing.

I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you!

My `AsyncTask`:

```
private class SaveMediaTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private int mediaType;

    public SaveMediaTask()
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        this.progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.progressDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Integer... mediaType)
    {
        //save to internal storage and return the path
        return path;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String path)
    {
        //by the time this runs, the UI has already tried to update itself on the main thread,
        //and found that myObject does not yet have a path. Once this runs, it is too late.
        myObject.setPath(path);

        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

How I call it, immediately after the user leaves the camera:

`new SaveMediaTask().execute(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);`

`//WAIT HERE AND DISPLAY PROGRESSDIALOG UNTIL TASK IS DONE`

`//update UI`

Comment: i cant really get what you want, but this answer right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499292/cant-show-alertdialog-in-doinbackground/27500068#27500068) will tell you how to structure your asynctask, also pay attention to your code needs, i do not think you need to check path from directly the main thread, i am thinking the asynctask has ways you can reach the ui,so use that to check your path to object and if its true call on postexecute and do your stuff, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the main thread didn't seem to wait for the results before
>   continuing.

the main thread wouldn't wait. This isn't how `AsyncTask` work. `AsyncTask` runs in background along with your main thread.

> then continue on the main thread to update the UI.

You don't need to continue on the main thread to update the UI once `AsyncTask` task is done, you could simply execute that *post* `doInBackground` task in `onPostExecute()` after dismissing the `progressDialog`, i.e `progressDialog.dismiss();` because `onPostExecute` runs in the UI thread.

Also, the good way is to start `progressDialog` inside `onPreExecute()` method and dismiss it in `onPostExecute` without checking  if the `progessDialog` is still showing or not because `onPostExecute()` would only run if the `doInBackground()` method is finished doing its job.

> What I want to do: Display a ProgressDialog until doInBackground()
>   finishes, then assign the path to my Object, and then continue on the
>   main thread to update the UI.

- Start ProgressDialog in `onPreExecute`,
- Assign the path to your object in `doInBackground`
- Dismiss ProgressDialog in `onPostExecute`,
- Continue your main thread work in `onPostExecute` since it runs in UI thread.

You can also update your UI thread while `doInBackground` is still running by invoking `publishProgress()`. Each call to this method will trigger the execution of `onProgressUpdate()` on the UI thread.

Tip: Its a good idea to dismiss `progressDialog` inside `onCancelled()` method beside dismissing it in `onPostExecute()` in case if you ever cancel your task inside `doInBackground`

Answer (score 3):

Your `onPostExecute` should notify your activity, that it can continue. So basically:

```
// Start the task from your activity
new SaveMediaTask().execute(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

// Method that will be called when task is completed
public void taskComplete() {
    // update UI
}
```

...

```
protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
    myObject.setPath(path);

    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    ((YourActivity)getActivity()).taskComplete();
}
```

Comment: That means I need to instantiate my Activity if Async Task is in some different custom class , because I wont be having getActivity() there to do something like  `((YourActivity)getActivity()).taskComplete();`

Or there is some better approach?

Comment: @eRaisedToX `AsyncTask` needs to know what `Activity` will display the `ProgressDialog` so you need some kind of a reference. How you do is for you to decide.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your code marked with `//update UI` to the end of your `onPostExecute` method. `onPostExecute` is always called on UI thread and is a good place to update UI to reflect the `AsyncTask` work results.